# Getting Parse Row Wrong ObjectId

Tags: java, android, listview, parse-platform, contextmenu

I have a listview that contains 4 objects in it.When I long press one of them ,a menu open with "Delete" option that I can delete the row.
However,I am getting the wrong row objetId for some reason and I can't figure out what is it I am doing wrong.

This is what I have done:

Creating context menu:

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

        // Get the list
        feedListView = (ListView)v;


        // Get the list item position
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;

    int position = info.position;
    position -= feedListView.getHeaderViewsCount();
    int finalPosition = position;



        if (ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername().equals(data.getUserName())){
            Log.e("Test","Same user + ObjectId = " + ((AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo).position);

            if (v.getId()==R.id.feedListView) {
                MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
            }

        }else{
            Log.e("Test","Not Your Post");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Its not your post", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }
```

Choosing from context menu:

```
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.deleteMenu){

        new AlertDialog.Builder(FeedActivity.this)
                .setTitle("Are you sure ?")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this post?")


                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Feed");

                            objects.get(finalPosition).deleteInBackground(new DeleteCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(ParseException e) {
                                    Log.e("Done","Item Deleted Successfully !!!");
                                    arrayList.remove(finalPosition);
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                            });


                            }
                        });



                    }
                })


                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                })


                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .show();



    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I fix it by adding these 2 lines:

The first:

```
MyData Editdata = (MyData) adapter.getItem(position);
```

To

```
MyData Editdata = (MyData) adapter.getItem(finalPosition);
```

The second line I added is(I added it because my listview display the same way):

```
query.orderByDescending("updatedAt");
```